# The use "not only" and "-ing form"

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, inversion

Could you tell me if the following sentence uses the "not only ... but also" and "-ing" correctly?

> The renovation project not only does not *avoid* but *precipitates* **living off-campus of students**.

> Not only does the renovation project not avoid but precipitate **living off-campus of students**.

Comment: "participle"...?

Comment: "Is it grammatical" questions are often the wrong question.  You can write grammatically but not make any sense.  You should at least explain why you think there is a problem here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some points before looking at the construction of the sentence:

1. The set phrase you are aiming for is "[not only... but also](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/only?q=not%20only)". The **also** is essential to complete the set phrase.
2. The end of the sentence would be better as "students living off-campus".
3. Precipitate needs an s in the second sentence.

---

To check whether you are using not only... but also correctly, re-assemble a sentence into two separate sentences- one containing the not only clause, and the other the but also clause. This works fine for the first sentence, but fails for the second one:

> The renovation project [does not avoid] students living off-campus.
> The renovation project [precipitates] students living off-campus.

> [The renovation project does not avoid] students living off-campus.
> [Precipitates students] living off-campus.

As you can see, "the renovation project* needs to be outside the not only part to give a sensible meaning to the but also part.

---

Note also that **[precipitate](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/precipitate)** means to make something happen suddenly or sooner than expected. Are you sure that's what you mean? Also, it's quite a formal word, and some native speakers might not understand it.

Comment: Can I have your suggestion for the way of applying inversion to the second sentence? and I'd like to use possessive for the "living...". Is "students", "students' "? or is your recommendation adjective clause instead? You're right. "precipitate" is not the best choice maybe intensify is the better option.

Comment: If it is generally understood among readers that students living off-campus is undesirable and is already a problem, you could simply refer to it as "the off-campus problem" or "the off-campus situation". You can then use the verb "exacerbate"... to make something that is already bad even worse. It's a classy word, but not formal.